# Values from data-attribute are outside of the double qotes

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to add additional information to a table by using the data attribute. This works well for the first two properties, but not for data-makeModelDescription, data-firstRegistration and data-mileage. Here I get as output

```
<tbody data-set="0"
       data-url="http://127.0.0.1:8888/selfstudy/projects/ad/res/test/212302246.php"
       data-makemodeldescription="Corvette" c5="" cabrio=""
       data-firstregistration="EZ" 03="" 2001="" data-mileage="96.000" km="">
```

but it should be:

```
<tbody data-set="0"
       data-url="http://127.0.0.1:8888/selfstudy/projects/ad/res/test/212302246.php"
       data-makemodeldescription="Corvette c5 cabrio"
       data-firstregistration="EZ 03/2001"
       data-mileage="96.000 km">
```

Source:

```
$.each(response, function(key, value) {
    $('#table__cars').append('<tbody 
        data-set='+key+' 
        data-url='+value.carDetailsURL+' 
        data-makeModelDescription='+value.makeModelDescription+' 
        data-firstRegistration='+value.firstRegistration+' 
        data-mileage='+value.mileage+'></tbody>');
```

Did anybody else also experience the same issue? Any tips how to debug this observation would be great too. I used console.log() to check if e. g. the value for value.mileage is correct and it is. Just when I use it as value for the data attribute I get this strange output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get is correct because you are writing values with spaces and not using quotes in your code. You should use

```
$.each(response, function(key, value) {
    $('#table__cars').append('<tbody 
        data-set="'+key+'" 
        data-url="'+value.carDetailsURL+'" 
        data-makeModelDescription="'+value.makeModelDescription+'" 
        data-firstRegistration="'+value.firstRegistration+'" 
        data-mileage="'+value.mileage+'"></tbody>');
```

Since you are using simple string catenation the new items are understood as new [empty attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/spec.html#syntax-attr-empty) when not quoted. See this example:

```
var val = "test foo bar";
$('#table__cars').append('<tbody data-val=' + val + '>');
```

This is exactly the same as saying:

```
$('#table__cars').append('<tbody data-val=test foo bar>');
```

HTML parsers will usually want the attributes to have values, so it is shown as empty:

```
<tbody data-val="test" foo="" bar="">
```

This is why the quotes are needed and even though [quotes are not required in certain cases](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/spec.html#syntax-attr-unquoted), I would recommend always using them. Otherwise everything might work in testing, but later when some value has a space it will break.

Also HTML versions before 5 will require quotes for attribute values.

Comment: Top! Works as expected. Do you also know a page that describes more in detail why values with spaces generate the output I commented in the ticket description? If not, also no big deal.

Comment: @HH Added explanation of the behaviour and some links